# ARC Welder app showing blank page on Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: google-chrome, android, chrome-extension

I am using Google Chrome version 41.0.2272.118 (64-bit) in Ubuntu 14.04.1.
I recently installed the ARC Welder extension from the Chrome Web Store.
When I opened it, it shows a blank window (see image below).

[image]

I tried to install apk files using the drag and drop method, but it also failed.

Why does it show a blank page?
How can I install Android apps in Chrome using ARC Welder?

Comment: -1: It's a beta app, any problems should be reported as bugs.

Comment: friend i know it is a beta app..
But i searched about this..
Search results says this problem not present in ARC Welder..
Problem is present in ARChon.. So that only i asked this question here for clear solution...

Answer (score 0):

Delete the app, logout of your account, then reinstall ARC Welder. This is what worked for me.